# Find the number of ordered pairs satisfying the following:

Tags: absolute-value

What are the number of ordered pairs of (x,y) satisfying the following system of simultaneous equations?
\begin{align*}
|x^2-2x|+y & =1\\
x^2+|y| & =1
\end{align*}

Comment: What have you attempted ? Are you aware that your issue means, in geometrical terms, the number of intersection points of two curves ?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I need to know how to solve the equations without graphing them.

Comment: But drawing the curves, even it does not provide a proof, gives you information angles of attack of the problem, in particular with the aim of seeing how to eliminate the absolute value symbols.

Comment: I got three solutions.

Comment: It's correct, please explain how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
    |x^2-2x| &= 1-y\\
    |y|    &= 1-x^2 \\
\end{align}

First we note that, if $y=0$, then $x = 1$.

Next we note that we need $1-x^2 \ge 0$; that is $-1 \le x \le 1$.

If $y < 0$, then $y=x^2-1$:

\begin{align}
   |x^2-2x| &= 1-y \\
   |x^2-2x| &= 2-x^2 &\text{(Square both sides.)} \\
   x^4-4x^3+4x^2 &= x^4-4x^2+ 4 \\
   4x^3-8x^2+4 &= 0 \\
   4(x-1)(x^2-x-1)&= 0 \\
   x &\in \{1,\, \frac 12(1-\sqrt 5),\, \frac 12(1+\sqrt 5)\} \\
   (x,y) &\in \left\{
                 \left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)
              \right\}
\end{align}

If $y \ge 0$, then $y=1-x^2$:

\begin{align}
   |x^2-2x| &= 1-y \\
   |x^2-2x| &= x^2 &\text{(Square both sides.)} \\
   x^4-4x^3+4x^2 &= x^4 \\
   -4x^2(x-1) &= 0 \\
   (x,y) &\in \{(0,1), (1,0) \}
\end{align}

So $(x,y) \in \left\{(0,1),(1,0),
              \left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}
              \right)\right\}$

Answer (score 2):

**Observe:** From the second equation $|y|=1-x^2$ it is clear that $x \in [-1,1]$. Thus $|x^2-2x|=|x||x-2|=|x|(2-x)$ (because for $x \in [-1,1]$ we will have $-3 \leq x-2 \leq -1$).

Now consider the following:

Case(1): Let $y \geq 0$, then the system is
\begin{align*}
|x|(2-x)+y & =1\\
x^2+y & =1
\end{align*}
which implies
$$|x|(2-x)=x^2.$$

Case(1a): if $x \geq 0$, then we have 
$$x(2-x)=x^2$$
Here we have only TWO solutions namely $\color{red}{x=0,1}$.

Case(1b): if $x < 0$, then we have 
$$-x(2-x)=x^2$$
Here we have NO solutions.

Case(2): Let $y < 0$, then the system is
\begin{align*}
|x|(2-x)+y & =1\\
x^2-y & =1
\end{align*}
Once again eliminate $y$ and proceed. Can you take it from here?